# Capybara fill_in number field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara

I have a rails app that I am testing using capybara. I am currently testing the form for creating a system. I can get the fill in method to work for text fields but I cant get it to work for number fields how can I accomplish this?

This is what i have tried:
    describe "manage systems" do

```
    it "adds a new system and displays the results"do 

        visit '/systems/new'

        fill_in 'name', with: "test system"
        fill_in 'responsible_personnel', with: " John"
        find_by_id('status').find("option[value='Unavailable']").click
        fill_in 'criticality', :with 1
    end
end
```

criticality is the number field that i am trying to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `:` on `with` facing the wrong way... could that be it?

```
fill_in 'criticality', :with 1
```

should be

```
fill_in 'criticality', with: 1
```

Comment: that fixed it, i had actually tried several ways of writing it but I guess i forgot to move the colon to the other side of the with.

Comment: Awesome! Yea, I suspect the older syntax of `fill_in 'criticality', :with => 1` would also work, but what you have here is the preferred syntax now.

Comment: Technically the :with option is supposed to be a string, so this should be `fill_in 'criticality', with: '1'`